# I have images along the left of my webpage, but I want text to be to the right of the images without ruining how the images are currently laid out

Tags: html, css, text, web, alignment

[Here's the live site](http://thecreaturecorporation.us.to) that's being hosted on google drive with a fowarded subdomain, sometimes the CSS doesn't load properly in chrome because it thinks there's an unsafe script

and for the code that I'm using will be shown below (however the images won't show, they are still the same size as on the live site)

http://jsfiddle.net/wtHec/

```
<style>
#text{
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}
#images{
    text-align: left;
    width: 220px;
}
p{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: -5px 0px 10px 10px;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
img{
    border: white solid 2px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 124px;
}
html {
    background: #383636;
}
</style>
<div id="text">
<p>
I want this text to be right next to the images<br>
now how do I fix this...
</p>
</div>
<div id="images">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/a88kO4couJ4"><img src="/resources/images/gungame.jpg"></a>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-pPzVRE9tjY"><img src="resources/images/FTB16.jpg"></a>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXF52t03dZc"><img src="resources/images/cmwep1.jpg"></a>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cl_qwysQZJE"><img src="resources/images/aosep1.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Create a grid system for laying them out. Here is a rough example. http://jsfiddle.net/wtHec/5/

Comment: that works but I need the text to keep on going along the page (not beneath the images) on thinner devices such as mobile

Answer (score 0):

Float both the images and the text `div`.

```
.images, .text{
    float:left;
}

.images{
    width:200px;
}

.text{
    width:400px;
}

.images img{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/9ejnk/

Comment: Don't forget about it, time to get some reputation and upvote answers! ;)

Comment: Ok this is what I wanted, however, if its being viewed on a smaller screen and the text length is too long, it puts it at the bottom instead of readjusting the text, how could I get it to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First the answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/mDef9/

Then some code:
CSS:

```
.clear {
    clear:both /*so you can start another set of image and text*/
}
.images{
    border: white solid 2px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 135px;
    float:left;    
}

.img1 {
    background: url(https://googledrive.com/host/0BwopdsZySMlGS2xCTUZ2bHl0QUU/resources/images/gungame.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 220px 135px;
}
.img2 {
    background: url(https://googledrive.com/host/0BwopdsZySMlGS2xCTUZ2bHl0QUU/resources/images/FTB16.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 220px 135px;
}
.caption{
    width: 200px; /*can be whatever you want*/
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="images">
    <a class="images img1" target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/a88kO4couJ4"></a> 
    <p class="caption">This is the text that will appear next to yhe image.</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <a class="images img2" target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/a88kO4couJ4"></a> 
    <p class="caption">This is some more boss text.</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Now heres some knowledge:

1. no need to put  elements inside of  elements you can declare backgrounds on block elements in css
2. your image tags need the the  "/" at the end
3. your #images div can not be the exact size of your images "since" you added margins you have to take this into account since you gave #images a fixed width of 220px. But your images were 220 + 10px margin-left & right thats 220+10+10=240px. So the div #images, width has to be >= 240px or set to "auto"
4. also the images were not showing up in jsfiddle because you were using relative paths. Those images are on another server so you have to use an absolute path if you are not hosting them. Example http://www.yousite.com/path-to-images/some-image.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'm a newbie to HTML and CSS so much appreciated!

Comment: Oh one more thing, I just want a column where I can type anything in without it affecting the images, so instead of like a description/caption for the images, I want it to have a panel in the middle that is separate from the images where I can type other information in, sorry if that doesn't make sense

Comment: Beneath the #images div add this

    <div id='anything'></div><div class="clear"></div>

In the CSS

    #anything{
        float:left;
    }

Please accept the answer since you achieved what you wanted :)